# 400 Bad Request error after every checkin in Plastic GUI with Jira issue Tracker

Tags: jira, plasticscm

I had a functioning setup. Then my admin made some Jira changes and now every time I do a checkin in PlasticSCM's Windows GUI I get the error message:

"Unable to log checkin data into issue tracker: The remote server returned an error (400) Bad Request."

Below is my configuration. I have tried removing the Custom Field ID but it still throws the error. What else can I try? How can I capture the request being sent? If I click "Test Connection" it is successful.

[image: Plastic Issue Tracker configuration]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: From your JIRA panel, could you check if the custom field is actually added to the issue? In the following forum post, we were discussing the same error: http://www.plasticscm.net/index.php?/topic/20177-jira-cloud-ondemand-integration-issues/#comment-36100

Comment: @CarlosAlbaZamanillo I asked my admin, and he walked through the steps and extracted the correct field # from a url. Does this have something to do with upgrading to the new version of Jira? I've tried to enabled plastic.exe logging but no log files are created. Any more ideas?

Comment: You need to enter the custom field ID in the Plastic configuration panel. But it's also important your admin to add to the issue the custom field (it's not added by default in JIRA OnDemand). Could you contact us at support at codicesoftware dot com ?

Answer (score 0):

Unsurprisingly, the issue was on the Jira side. I got my Admin to make me an Admin so I could troubleshoot.

In plastic, get in a branch tied to a specific jira ticket. Check in a change so you get the error message. Good. Now, go to that Jira ticket. under the "Admin" button in the top middle, select "Add field". Find the field tied to the custom field number Id in plastic's configuration. If you followed Plastic's tutorials to set all this up originally, the field is called "Plastic SCM".

Now, it won't actually add the field, since the field is present on the page, but hidden because it has no value. You will see an "Edit" option. pick that. Enter any text like "Empty text". This is what is key, I think. It might be that the value was null, and now that you set it to an actual string, the field shows up. With this new text value, the Plastic SCM field should be displayed on the page somewhere. If you are still having trouble , choose "Where is my field?" from the admin button and look at the information displayed.

Now, make a minor change in your code and do a new checkin in plastic. No error message, right? Yay. Also, you should see check-in information displayed in the ticket now.

I know what you are thinking, sure, that worked for just one ticket, what about all the rest? Well, it seems like making this change has a cascade effect on other tickets in the same project, so you won't have to do it repeatedly. Weird.